# Extract array from XML dictionary

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing, nsarray

Is it possible to extract an ordered array of keys from the XML file below:

Basically what I want is an array that looks like this and in this order:
["key1","key2","myKey3","key4","key5"]

The problem is that if I convert to NSDictionary first and then loop through the keys I lose the order.

I was hoping to be able to do this without changing the web server.

Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>key1</key>
    <array>
        <string></string>
        <string>title1</string>
        <string>disabled</string>
    </array>
    <key>key2</key>
    <array>
        <string></string>
        <string>title2</string>
        <string>disabled</string>
    </array>
    <key>myKey3</key>
    <array>
        <string></string>
        <string>title3</string>
    </array>
    <key>key4</key>
    <array>
        <string></string>
        <string>title4</string>
        <string>disabled</string>
    </array>
    <key>key5</key>
    <array>
        <string></string>
        <string>title5</string>
        <string>disabled</string>
    </array>
</plist>
```

Comment: Don't think about order in a Dictionary, or you misunderstood its purpose. Order shouldn't be important in a dictionary because access is through key not index. And that seems more like a plist file (easy transformation method) than a "true" xml (parsing is more complex).

Comment: Thanks but maybe you misunderstood my question. I am looking to convert that XML file into an array. If I convert it to a dictionary and then to an array it won't keep the order b/c the dictionary is an unordered collection. That is from a plist true but it's exactly the same file that I asked to be posted on the web server so I def. need to parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could utilize [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsxmlparser?language=objc). You need to implement NSXMLParserDelegate and in the `parser:didStartElement:` if `elementName` is equal to "key", then in the next `parser:foundCharacters:` call you add the key value into an `NSMutableArray`. At the end you get an ordered array of keys.

When you have your ordered keys, you can use them to iterate through the `NSDictionary` (`dict` below) that you have in order:

```
for (NSString *key in orderedKeys) {
    NSArray *properties = dict[key];
    ...
}
```

See this for a concrete code example - [NSXMLParser Simple Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21791702/nsxmlparser-simple-example)

Comment: Interesting thanks. I will check this out tomorrow and let you know how it works.

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. It's cool that most people actually want to be helpful here instead of just downvoting for the heck of it.